# CombineLatest multiple PassthroughSubject no output

Tags: ios, swift, combine

```
let p1: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never> = .init()
let p2: PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never> = .init()

var pub1: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    return p1.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var pub2: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    return p2.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var sub: AnyCancellable?

sub = Publishers.CombineLatest(pub1, pub2).sink(receiveValue: { output in
    print("output: \(output)")
})

p1.send(4)
// nothing printed
p2.send(false)
// printed: output: (4, false)
```

why is there no output when p1 sends `4`? How should I structure the code such that when either p1 pr p2 sends a value, there is an output?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: hi @matt I was expecting 4 being printed out. Since its a tuple, could it possibly be `(4, nil)` ?

Comment: But nil is not a Bool. I'm still not understanding what you want / expect. Play out the scenario. 4 is sent on the first publisher and you get what? True is sent on the second publisher and you get what? I'm trying to imagine the rule you are expecting the pipeline to follow.

Comment: hi @matt thanks for replying. I think I found the answer which is to use a CurrentValueSubject instead.

`let p1: CurrentValueSubject<Int?, Never> = .init(nil)`
`let p2: CurrentValueSubject<Bool?, Never> = .init(nil)`

I want to observe two publishers and process the output even if only 1 publisher is emitting a value.

Answer (score 1):

The combineLatest operator can't emit something until every publisher it is observing emits something (a publisher that hasn't emitted a value doesn't have a "latest value" to emit.)

As you mention in comments, one way to get around this is to use a CurrentValueSubject so that there *is* a "latest value" for each child publisher.

Another way is to use `.prepend` to emit a value for `combineLatest` to use.

As in:

```
sub = Publishers.CombineLatest(pub1.prepend(0), pub2.prepend(false)).sink(receiveValue: { output in
    print("output: \(output)")
})
```